# How does Ruby's ActiveSupport "between?" function handle impossible times?

Tags: ruby, datetime, time, activesupport

I'm using the [ActiveSupport `between?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/between%3F) to determine if a time is between 8 AM and 4:45 PM, and I accidentally was putting a later time as the first argument and the earlier time as the second, like so:

```
# variable `time` gets set up here
unless time.between?(Time.local(time.year, time.month, time.day, 8), Time.local(time.year, time.month, time.day, 4, 45))
  # short circuit
end
# do stuff
```

I know this is wrong since I should have it use `16, 45` instead of `4, 45` so I was able to fix the bug, but I couldn't find documentation on what happens in this case, since it wasn't throwing any errors which was strange to me.  It seemed that it was always returning `true`, since the inside of this `unless` statement never executed during testing, which was bizarre, unexpected behavior to me.  I would assume it would either throw some error or always return false, since technically no time can be between 8 AM and 4:45 AM.

So how does the `between?` function actually handle times that are "impossible", e.g. the later time comes before the earlier time?

Comment: Hi, welcome to S.O. Please show a reproducible example for this, as what you mention doesn't look like something possible. If you call `Time.zone.now.between?(Time.zone.tomorrow, Time.zone.yesterday)` that is going to return `false`, so I guess the error is in the data you're handling.

Comment: _"It seemed that it was always returning `true`"_ – what value for `time` did show that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It always returns `false`, not true. You can try yourself with every number for hours:

```
my_time = Time.local(2022, 05, 8, 6)
eight = Time.local(2022, 05, 8, 8)
four = Time.local(2022, 05, 8, 4)

puts my_time.between?(eight, four)
```

and will always return `false`

Comment: Agree with you, just notice in your example you're using `Time`, not `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` which is what the OP is asking, but the result will be the same anyway.

Comment: In this example I used the same `Time.local` that OP is referring to.

Comment: Agree, but for `time.between?`, you don't really know the class type for `time` and the OP is asking about the ActiveSupport `between?`. Anyway, I can understand isn't really clear without more context from the OP.